# Opencart IE issue cart dropdown not working works fine in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, opencart

For the life of me i cannot find the issue or confict that is causing the opencart cart header to work in IE. It works fine in other browsers.

When you visit a product on my site and press (add to cart) it doesn't seem to ajax update the cart nor will the cart display when clicked.

To replicate the problem go to http://www.hollinwoodhydroponics.co.uk/ph-nutrient-management/ph-buffer-4 in IE and try to add to cart. Also notice the Success: Message doesn't display.

Opencart 1.5.1.3
Update:It All works on the catagory page so im thinking this may be my issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window.console) {var console = {};}
if (!console.log) {console.log = function() {};}

function updatePx() {
console.log('OPU: updatePx() called');
    var ajaxurl = 'index.php?option=com_aceshop&format=raw&tmpl=component&route=product/option_price_update/updatePrice';

jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jQuery(':input[name^="option"][type=\'checkbox\']:checked, :input[type=\'hidden\'], :input[name^="option"][type=\'radio\']:checked, select[name^="option"], :input[name=\'quantity\']'),

    success: function (mydata) {
        console.log('OPU: mydate.price'+mydata.price);
        console.log('OPU: mydate.special'+mydata.special);
        console.log('OPU: mydate.tax'+mydata.tax);

        // Update the main price with the new price.

        jQuery('#opu_price').fadeOut('100').queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.price); n();}).fadeIn('100');
        jQuery('#opu_special').fadeOut('100').delay(100).queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.special); n();}).fadeIn('100');
        jQuery('#opu_tax').fadeOut('100').delay(200).queue(function(n){jQuery(this).html(mydata.tax); n();}).fadeIn('100');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
console.log('OPU: initialized');
var $updateOnLoad = false; // Change to true if using 1.4.x or want to force an update on page load

// Update on initial page load for 1.4.x only
if ($updateOnLoad) {
    updatePx();
}

// Update whenever the triggerable page inputs are changed
jQuery(':input[name^="option"],:input[name^="quantity"]').change(function(){
    updatePx();
});

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight to the issue or conflict that could be causing this.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening with yours, but I use OpenCart and when I just tested it in IE the success message displayed.

My guess is that you have some jquery variables clashing.  If you have added any jquery scripts yourself, remove it and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are also using mootools.  My guess is that is the source of your problem, take a look here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: indeed i thought mootools was the issue so i implemented 
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
so im thinking the issue may be as you said the custom jquery im using. Thanks for getting me started :)

Comment: cannot figure out where the conflict is :( how does that script above break IE... could murder bill right now :P

Comment: cut your page back to bare bones, add scripts one at a time, test after each one

Comment: cheers for the tip, that narrowed it down as it works barebones so defiantly a conflict in my styling.
considering the easy option and making a separate non html5 styling for IE, hey if google does it why not.

Comment: Great.  If my answer is does the job, do the SO thing and accept it, it encourages people to answer your questions when you are seen to do that.